# Homework Help Java and Multidimensional Arrays

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

HW11

Instructions
Create an application that contains two arrays.  One for the student name and one multi-dimensional array to hold 4 test scores for each student.  Have the program calculate the average test score for each student and display the result.

Save the application as  StudentScores.java

Upload or copy the java file into the dropbox and submit

```
public class StudentScores {
   public static void main(String [] args) {
      String [] StudentNames = { "James" + "Cody" + "Thad" + "Zach" };
      double [][] scores = { {1, 84, 95, 67, 78},
                             {2, 96, 100, 87, 92},
                             {3, 90, 85, 56, 77},
                             {4, 83, 87, 92, 74}};

     double avg = 0.0;                     
     double sum = 0.0;                
     
                         
    for(int r = 0; r < scores.length; r++) {
         System.out.print("Student " + StudentNames + " grades: ");
         for(int c = 1; c < scores[r].length; c++) {
            System.out.print(scores[r][c] + " ");
            sum = sum + scores[r][c];
         }
         System.out.println();      
      avg = sum / (scores[r].length - 1);
      System.out.println("Average scores: " + avg);
      sum = 0;
         }
        }
       }
```

This is my current code. The calculator is working my issue is currently not being able to find a method to display the string array in a way that displays the names correctly alongside their grades and averages.

Comment: You need to find a way to print each element of the student names array, right now it's just printing the address, and not the values.

Comment: In the initialization of `studentNames` you need comma between the names, not plus. (And the variable name should begin with a small `s` in Java.)

Comment: Poor title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.